# I get wrong characters when retreiving the message body of an email using TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

In my application (Windows 10, Delphi 10.4), I use `TIdIMAP4` to retrieve an email's body from the server with this code:

```pascal
var aBody : string := '';
UIDRetrieveTextPeek2(MsgID,aBody);
```

If the returned string starts with `<!DOCTYPE html>'#$D#$A'<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:...`

or

`<html><head><style type="text/css">'#$D#$A'@media screen and (max-width:480px) {'#$D#$A'  .background_inner {'#$D#$A'    padding: 0!important;'#$D#$A'....`

I can see the HTML content formed right, but when it starts with:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.='#$D#$A'w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">=0A<html xmlns=3D"http://www.='#$D#$A'w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><style type=3D"text/css" media=3D"all">=0A=09a:hov='#$D#$A'er {=09color: red;=09}=0A=09a {=0A=09=09text-decoration: underline;=0A=09='#$D#$A'=09color: #0088cc;=0A=09}....`

The HTML is malformed (`=0A=09a:hov='#$D#$A'er {=09color: red;=09}=0A=09a {=0A=09=09text-decoration: underline;=0A=09=`)

What can I do to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Here is a reproducible example:

```pascal
unit Unit11;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  IdIMAP4,IdMessage,IdSSLOpenSSL,IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase, IdBaseComponent, IdIntercept, IdLogBase, IdLogFile;

type
  TForm11 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form11: TForm11;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var SearchInfo: array of TIdIMAP4SearchRec;
    IdMessage1: TIdMessage;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    i, msgs : integer;
    MsgID, aBody : string;
begin
    with TIdIMAP4.create do try
        IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
        IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
        IOhandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
        authType := iatUserPass;
        Host := 'imap.gmail.com';
        userName := 'xxxxxxxxxx';
        password := 'yyyyyyyyyy';
        UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
        if Connect(TRUE) then
        try
            SelectMailBox('INBOX');
            SetLength(SearchInfo, 1);
            SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skAll;
            if SearchMailBox(SearchInfo)
            and (High(MailBox.SearchResult) > -1) then
            try
                msgs := High(MailBox.SearchResult)+1;

                for i := 0 to msgs - 1 do
                begin
                    MsgID := '';
                    GetUID(MailBox.SearchResult[i], MsgID);
                    // some bodyies are unreadable, some ok and some as the following are unencoded QP
                    if MsgID = '16805' then begin
                        var IdLogFile1: TIdLogFile := TIdLogFile.Create(nil);
                        IdLogFile1.Filename := 'log.txt';
                        intercept := IdLogFile1;
                        IdLogFile1.Active := TRUE;
                        UIDRetrieveTextPeek2(MsgID,aBody);
                        IdLogFile1.Active := FALSE;
                        IdLogFile1.Free;
                    end;
                end;
            finally

            end;
        finally

        end;
    finally
        IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.free;
    end;
end;

end.
```

And its captured log:

```
Sent 26/7/2021 10:09:45 ??: C55 UID FETCH 16805 (BODYSTRUCTURE)<EOL>
Recv 26/7/2021 10:09:45 ??: * 51 FETCH (UID 16805 BODYSTRUCTURE (("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "8BIT" 760 16 NIL NIL NIL)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "QUOTED-PRINTABLE" 3962 80 NIL NIL NIL) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "----=_NextPart_000_0008_01D583AF.54009F20") NIL NIL))<EOL>
Recv 26/7/2021 10:09:45 ??: C55 OK Success<EOL>
Sent 26/7/2021 10:09:45 ??: C56 UID FETCH 16805 (BODY.PEEK[2])<EOL>
Recv 26/7/2021 10:09:46 ??: * 51 FETCH (UID 16805 BODY[2] 
Recv 26/7/2021 10:09:46 ??: {3962}<EOL>
Recv 26/7/2021 10:09:46 ??: <html><EOL>    <head><EOL>  <style type=3D"text/css"><EOL>            body, td, span, p, th { font-size: 11px; }<EOL>       table.html-email {margin:10px auto;background:#fff;border:solid =<EOL>#dad8d8 1px;}<EOL>        .html-email tr{border-bottom : 1px solid #eee;}<EOL>        span.grey {color:#666;}<EOL>        span.date {color:#666;font-size: 10px;}<EOL>        a.default:link, a.default:hover, a.default:visited =<EOL>{color:#666;line-height:25px;background: #f2f2f2;margin: 10px ;padding: =<EOL>3px 8px 1px 8px;border: solid #CAC9C9 1px;border-radius: =<EOL>4px;-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;text-shadow: 1px =<EOL>1px 1px #f2f2f2;font-size: 12px;background-position: 0px 0px;display: =<EOL>inline-block;text-decoration: none;}<EOL>       a.default:hover {color:#888;background: #f8f8f8;}<EOL>      .cart-summary{ }<EOL>       .html-email th { background: #ccc;margin: 0px;padding: 10px;}<EOL>      .sectiontableentry2, .html-email th, .cart-summary th{ background: =<EOL>#ccc;margin: 0px;padding: 10px;}<EOL>      .sectiontableentry1, .html-email td, .cart-summary td {background: =<EOL>#fff;margin: 0px;padding: 10px;}<EOL>  </style><EOL><EOL>    </head><EOL><EOL>    <body style=3D"background: #F2F2F2;word-wrap: break-word;"><EOL> <div style=3D"background-color: #e6e6e6;" width=3D"100%"><EOL>      <table style=3D"margin: auto;" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0"  =<EOL>><EOL>        <tr><EOL>           <td><EOL>           <table width=3D"100%" border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" =<EOL>cellspacing=3D"0" class=3D"html-email"><EOL>             <tr><EOL>               <td ><EOL><EOL>                 =CE=9A=CE=B1=CE=BB=CF=8E=CF=82 =<EOL>=CE=AE=CF=81=CE=B8=CE=B1=CF=84=CE=B5 =CF=83=CF=84=CE=BF =<EOL>=CE=91=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=A5=CE=A1=CE=A9 =<EOL>=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=93=CE=95=CE=A9=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=99=CE=9F=CE=A5  =<EOL>              <br /><EOL>                                 </td><EOL>              </tr><EOL>          </table><EOL><EOL>          <table class=3D"html-email" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" =<EOL>border=3D"0" width=3D"100%"><EOL>             <tr><EOL>               <th width=3D"100%"><EOL>                    =CE=A4=CE=B1 =CF=83=CF=84=CE=BF=CE=B9=CF=87=CE=B5=CE=AF=CE=B1 =<EOL>=CF=84=CE=B7=CF=82 =CE=B5=CE=B3=CE=B3=CF=81=CE=B1=CF=86=CE=AE=CF=82 =<EOL>=CF=83=CE=B1=CF=82                </th><EOL><EOL>             </tr><EOL>              <tr><EOL>               <td valign=3D"top" width=3D"100%"><EOL>                 =CE=8C=CE=BD=CE=BF=CE=BC=CE=B1 =<EOL>=CF=83=CF=8D=CE=BD=CE=B4=CE=B5=CF=83=CE=B7=CF=82dpap<br />=CE=A4=CE=BF =<EOL>=CF=8C=CE=BD=CE=BF=CE=BC=CE=B1 =CF=80=CE=BF=CF=85 =<EOL>=CE=B5=CE=BC=CF=86=CE=B1=CE=BD=CE=AF=CE=B6=CE=B5=CF=84=CE=B1=CE=B9: =<EOL>=CE=91=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=A5=CE=A1=CE=A9 =<EOL>=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=93=CE=95=CE=A9=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=99=CE=9F=CE=A5<=<EOL>br />O =CE=BA=CF=89=CE=B4=CE=B9=CE=BA=CF=8C=CF=82 =<EOL>=CF=83=CE=B1=CF=82staran<br /><br />=CE=97 =<EOL>=CE=B4=CE=B9=CE=B5=CF=8D=CE=B8=CF=85=CE=BD=CF=83=CE=B7 =<EOL>=CF=83=CE=B1=CF=82: <br />E-Mail: dpapdpap@gmail.com<br =<EOL>/>=CE=A0=CF=81=CE=BF=CE=B2=CE=B1=CE=BB=CE=BB=CF=8C=CE=BC=CE=B5=CE=BD=CE=BF=<EOL> =CF=8C=CE=BD=CE=BF=CE=BC=CE=B1: =CE=91=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=A5=CE=A1=CE=A9 =<EOL>=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=93=CE=95=CE=A9=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=99=CE=9F=CE=A5<=<EOL>br />=CE=9F=CE=BD=CE=BF=CE=BC=CE=B1 =<EOL>=CE=B5=CF=84=CE=B1=CE=B9=CF=81=CE=AF=CE=B1=CF=82: =<EOL>=CE=91.=CE=94.=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=93=CE=95=CE=A9=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=99=<EOL>=CE=9F=CE=A5<br />=CE=9F=CE=BD=CE=BF=CE=BC=CE=B1: =<EOL>=CE=91=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=A5=CE=A1=CE=A9<br =<EOL>/>=CE=95=CF=80=CE=AF=CE=B8=CE=B5=CF=84=CE=BF: =<EOL>=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=A0=CE=91=CE=93=CE=95=CE=A9=CE=A1=CE=93=CE=99=CE=9F=CE=A5<=<EOL>br />=CE=94=CE=B9=CE=B5=CF=8D=CE=B8=CF=85=CE=BD=CF=83=CE=B7 1: =<EOL>=CE=A6=CE=95=CE=99=CE=94=CE=99=CE=A0=CE=A0=CE=99=CE=94=CE=9F=CE=A5 2<br =<EOL>/>=CE=A4=CE=B1=CF=87. =CE=BA=CF=89=CE=B4=CE=B9=CE=BA=CF=8C=CF=82: =<EOL>32131<br />=CE=A0=CF=8C=CE=BB=CE=B7: =<EOL>=CE=9B=CE=99=CE=92=CE=91=CE=94=CE=95=CE=99=CE=91<br =<EOL>/>=CE=A7=CF=8E=CF=81=CE=B1: Greece<br />=CE=9D=CE=BF=CE=BC=CF=8C=CF=82 / =<EOL>=CE=A0=CE=B5=CF=81=CE=B9=CE=BF=CF=87=CE=AE: =<EOL>=CE=92=CE=9F=CE=99=CE=A9=CE=A4=CE=99=CE=91=CE=A3<br =<EOL>/>=CE=A4=CE=B7=CE=BB.: 2261089120<br />=CE=BA=CE=B9=CE=BD.: =<EOL>6974398860<br />               </td><EOL>              </tr><EOL>          </table><EOL>           </td><EOL>      </tr><EOL>      </table><EOL>   </div><EOL>    </body><EOL></html><EOL><EOL>
Recv 26/7/2021 10:09:46 ??: )<EOL>
Recv 26/7/2021 10:09:46 ??: C56 OK Success<EOL>
```

Comment: It is not malformed. The email is MIME encoded, and the piece you are looking at is using "quoted-printable" encoding. You are simply peeking at the *raw* content. You will have to decode it if you want actual characters. Indy has a `TIdDecoderQuotedPrintable` class available

Comment: @RemyLebeau. Thanks using 
if pos('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC',aBody) = 1 then
                                aBody := IdDecoderQuotedPrintable1.DecodeString(aBody);
I get the correct HTML layout but not in my language.

Comment: actually, after reviewing the source code for `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()`, it should be QP-decoding the text automatically for you, unless the email in question is not claiming that the text is QP-encoded, even though it clearly is. Can you show the raw data of the email in question?

Comment: UIDRetrieveTextPeek2(MsgID,aBody) gives 

```'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.='#$D#$A'w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">=0A<html xmlns=3D"http://www.='#$D#$A'w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><style type=3D"text/css" media=3D"all">=0A=09a:hov='#$D#$A'er {=09color: red;=09}=0A=09a {=0A=09=09text-decoration: underline;=0A=09='#$D#$A'=09color: #0088cc;=0A=09}...```

Comment: That is not what I asked for.  I meant the **RAW** data of the ENTIRE email, as it is stored on the server.  Not the PIECE of the email that you are peeking (you already showed that in your question). Or, at least, the RAW data of the 2 `UID FETCH` commands that `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` is issuing, which you can get from a packet sniffer like Wireshark, or by attaching one of Indy's `TIdLog....` components to the `TIdIMAP4.Intercept` property

Comment: @RemyLebeau. I have the log file from TIdLog component. How can I upload it ?

Comment: just [edit] your question to include the text of the log.

Comment: Is bigger than allowed. If you please download it from my Googlo drive here https://drive.google.com/file/d/19JtzWr2CtNWz_2k0GCyexIL_UhvItGDC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That is not how this site works, but whatever, I've sent a request to gain access to that file. I don't need the whole log, just the 2 command responses for `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()`, that should not be too big to include in your question.

Comment: Are you really using `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()`? It should send `UID FETCH ### (BODYSTRUCTURE)` and `UID FETCH ### (BODY.PEEK[#])`, but I don't see any `BODYSTRUCTURE`s in your log, and each `BODY.PEEK[#]` is missing a part number. This log looks like what the various `UIDRetrievePart...()` methods would send, but they require you to explicitly specify an `APartNum` and  `AContentTransferEncoding` (like `'quoted-printable'`) in order to download and decode text, since they assume you have already downloaded an email's body structure beforehand to discover its available parts and their encodings.

Comment: You can delete the log now, I'm sure you don't want the whole world knowing your username and password (you should have stripped them out before uploading the file)

Comment: Its ok. The password isn't real

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235312/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-jim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIdIMAP4.UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` first retrieves the email's body structure, then scans it looking for the first text part that has a non-zero size reported. If none are found, the last text part is used.  It then uses the chosen part's specified byte encoding and charset to decode the part's text for output.

At least, that is the theory, anyway.

In your log, the email in question has 2 text parts being reported by the IMAP server:

- `text/plain`, size 760, encoding `"8BIT"`, charset `"utf-8"`
- `text/html`, size 3962, encoding `"QUOTED-PRINTABLE"`, charset `"utf-8"`

However, in comments, you say that `UIDRetrieveStructure()` (which `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` uses internally) is actually reporting 3 text parts instead:

- `multipart/alternative`
- `text/plain`, size 760, encoding `"8BIT"`, charset `"utf-8"`
- `text/html`, size 3962, encoding `"QUOTED-PRINTABLE"`, charset `"utf-8"`

Your log shows `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` is retrieving `BODY.PEEK[2]`, so it *thinks* it is requesting the content of the `text/plain` part (which makes sense, since that is the first non-empty text part), but is *actually* requesting the content of the `text/html` part instead. That will have to be fixed.  I have opened a ticket for that:

[#368 TIdIMAP4.InternalRetrieveText() does not retreive text correctly](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/368)

Since the byte encoding of the `text/plain` part is `8bit`, `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` is not trying to decode the QP-encoded characters in the HTML, which explains why you are seeing them (`=0A`, `=3D`, `=09`, etc) in the output `string`.

Comment: With this change                        ``UIDRetrieveStructure(MsgID,IdImapMessageParts);
                        IdLogFile1.Active := FALSE;``  I receive this log ``Sent 27/7/2021 9:34:07 ??: C55 UID FETCH 16805 (BODYSTRUCTURE)<EOL>
Recv 27/7/2021 9:34:07 ??: * 51 FETCH (UID 16805 BODYSTRUCTURE (("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "8BIT" 760 16 NIL NIL NIL)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "QUOTED-PRINTABLE" 3962 80 NIL NIL NIL) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "----=_NextPart_000_0008_01D583AF.54009F20") NIL NIL))<EOL>
Recv 27/7/2021 9:34:07 ??: C55 OK Success<EOL>``

Comment: That is not what I asked you for.  I did not need a new log. I need to know what the content of the `IdImapMessageParts` looks like after `UIDRetrieveStructure()` exits, specifically the `ContentTransferEncoding` property of each item in the list.

Comment: ``IdImapMessageParts[0].ContentTransferEncoding = ''`` 
  ``IdImapMessageParts[1].ContentTransferEncoding = '8BIT'``   ``IdImapMessageParts[2].ContentTransferEncoding = 'QUOTED-PRINTABLE'``

Comment: What does the rest of `IdImapMessageParts[0]` look like? I don't think that should be present. But in any case, I don't know what is going on.  What you have shown does not match `TIdIMAP4`'s source code. Something weird is going on, and I simplyhave no way to debug it myself right now

Comment: item 0
``BodyType = alternative
Encoding = 1
CharSet  = 
ContentTransferEncoding = 
Size     = 0
ImapPartNumber = ``

item 1
``BodyType = TEXT
Encoding = 1
CharSet  = utf-8
ContentTransferEncoding = 8BIT
Size     = 760
ImapPartNumber = 1``

item 2
``BodyType = TEXT
Encoding = 1
CharSet  = utf-8
ContentTransferEncoding = QUOTED-PRINTABLE
Size     = 3962
ImapPartNumber = 2``

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to investigate why the `alternative` part is being reported this way. In the meantime, I have updated my answer to explain the problem.

Comment: I think that client asks for 1-based parts but server treats them as 0-based. Meanwhile I use a workaround for this : I find by myself the body examining the parts for the last non-zero text part

Comment: "*but server treats them as 0-based*" - no, that is not the reason. It is the presence of the `multipart/alternative` part as the 1st item of the `TIdImapMessageParts` that is throwing things off. After `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` decides which item to request, it be using the item's `ImapPartNumber`, but is currently not. I will fix that.

Comment: I have checked in a fix to [Indy's repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/). Note that `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` should now request and decode the `text/plain` part correctly as the 1st non-empty text, not the `text/html` anymore. If you were expecting the HTML, then `UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` wasn't the appropriate method to use in the first place. You would have to use `UIDRetrieveStructure()` to find the HTML part yourself, and then use `UIDRetrievePart/Peek()` to download it.

Comment: I installed your fix but the result not changed. ``UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()`` still decodes the ``Text/HTML`` part.  ``UIDRetrieveStructure()`` still returns the same 3 parts. The only difference is that the log is ``Sent 28/7/2021 2:50:30 ??: C57 UID FETCH 16805 (BODYSTRUCTURE)<EOL>
Recv 28/7/2021 2:50:30 ??: * 51 FETCH (UID 16805 BODYSTRUCTURE (("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "8BIT" 760 16 NIL NIL NIL)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "utf-8") NIL NIL "QUOTED-PRINTABLE" 3962 80 NIL NIL NIL) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "----=_NextPart_000_0008_01D583AF.54009F20") NIL NIL))<EOL>...``

Comment: "*`UIDRetrieveTextPeek2()` still decodes the Text/HTML part*" - given the structure shown, that should not be possible under the new code, the 2nd `FETCH` should now be requesting `BODY.PEEK[1]` instead of `BODY.PEEK[2]` as before. So I have to assume that when you downloaded the new code, it did not actually take effect in your build, the old version is likely still being used.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Because deleting the bpls, dcps and trying to rebuild IMAP4 package I had the message "Delphi uses ...." I replaced the old IMAP4.pas of the installation package with the new one. Then I repeared Delphi hoping (wrongly) to rebuild IMAP4 but it did not succeed.

Comment: It is not enough to just replace the `IdIMAP4.pas` file, you have to recompile the entire Indy library and install the updated BPLs into the IDE (or at least point your project to where the updated `.pas`/`.dcp` files are located). [Install Instructions](https://web.archive.org/web/20200925081341/http://ww2.indyproject.org/Sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.EN.aspx)

Comment: @jim have you had any luck getting the latest Indy code installed and tested?

Comment: @Remmy Lebeau, sorry for late answer. I just read your message. I didn't try to rebuild IMAP4 because is dificult to me. I now use with success the follwing code "LCharSet := uppercase(LThePart.CharSet);
  LContentTransferEncoding := ThePart.ContentTransferEncoding;
var st : TStringStream := TStringStream.Create;                                    UIDRetrievePartPeek(MsgID,LTextPartNum,TStream(st),LContentTransferEncoding);
if uppercase(LCharSet) = 'UTF-8'
then aBody := UTF8toString(st.DataString)
else aBody := st.DataString;
and it works